# How to combine objects in tuples when multi-index conditions are met

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, multi-index

I'm trying to combine Dates (`datetime.date` format) into Times (`datetime.datetime` format).

Dates and Times were extracted separately from a single "main list" which contained mixed info. For that reason, I've also kept their indexes (from the "main list") in tuples to allow me to re-integrate these later, back into the "main list" where they belong.

Goes like so:

```
Dates = [(i,date)]
Times = [(i,time)]
```

Sample from Dates list:

```
[(0, datetime.date(2021, 2, 5)),
 (118, datetime.date(2021, 2, 6)),
 (176, datetime.date(2021, 2, 7))]
```

Sample from Times list:

```
[(1, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 6, 0)),
 (6, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 6, 30)),
 (11, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 0)),...
 (150, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 30)),
 (155, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 30)),
 (160, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 0)),
 (180, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 30)),...
 (185, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 0)),
 (190, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 30))]
```

## The part I can't figure how to code...

For any saved indexes (in tuples) from the Times list which are between succeeding saved indexes (in tuples) from the Dates list, need to integrate the date at inferior index.

In other words, the logic needs to be:

- any time indexes (e.g. Times[1][0]) between index at Date[0][0] and Date[1][0] (so, saved indexes [0::118]) need to integrate Date[0][1].
- any time indexes (e.g. Times[1][0]) between index at Date[1][0] and Date[2][0] (so, saved indexes [118::176]) need to integrate Date[0][1].

### Anyone good in maths, up for the challenge?

Additionally, I know this bit will allow me to combine dates into each time:

```
da = datetime.date(2021, 2, 5)
ti = datetime.time(6, 0)

date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.combine(da,ti)
```

I've also tried playing around with these:

```
for i1,(true_index1,date) in zip(range(len(dates)),dates):
    for i2,(true_index2,time) in zip(range(len(times)),times):
```